# .Net Framwork Web App Execution Timeout Expired

Tags: sql-server, .net-4.8

I'm trying to run a query on a SQL Server Database from a Web App and after 30 seconds I get the following error:

`Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`

I know that the default execution time is 30 seconds but I have tried to change the Timeout in multiple places. In the Web App connection string I have:

`Timeout=300;connection lifetime=5;`

The Web App uses a DLL that connects to the database for running queries and when I make the command in the DLL I have:

`Comm.CommandTimeout = 5 * 60;`

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I've looked this issue up for a while now and can't seem to figure out where I'm going wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: The command timeout needs to be set via the `SqlCommand.CommandTimeout` property, not the connection string. That said, 30 seconds may be a long time for a web app. Perhaps query/index tuning is a better solution than increasing the command titmeout.

Comment: @DanGuzman I do set it with ```Comm.CommandTimeout = 5 * 60;``` which is handled by the DLL. It's for 5 minutes as it's a big query but it will still timeout after 30 seconds, the query in SSMS takes 43  seconds usually.